# Showing if $A\in DSPACE(n^c) \text{ or } DTIME(n^c)$ then $EXP^A \neq EXP$ and $EXP^A= EXP$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity, oracle-machines, oracles

> 1. If a language $A\in DSPACE(n^c)$, then $EXP^A\neq EXP$
> 2. If a language $A\in DTIME(n^c)$, then $EXP^A= EXP$

What I tried:

1. Since it's impossible to show that $EXP \subseteq EXP^A$ because:

   - We know that $DSPACE(n^c)\subseteq  DTIME(2^{n^c})$
   - exponential functions aren't closed to composition
   - so from the above two, suppose we have a TM $M\in EXP$, such that M will simulate $A$ to compensate for not having a an oracle for A, this will yield a $O(2^{2^{n^c}})$ runtime.
2. It's true since simulating $A$ even an exponential amount will still be exponential since polynomials are closed to composition.

Comment: But $\mathsf{PSPACE}$ is low for $\mathsf{EXP}$, isn't it?

Comment: My course didn't fully cover oracles so I don't know that (they didn't say the term "low for..." either). I'm trying to find a proof for that but I can't find it, do you know where a proof can be found? @rus9384

Comment: Ah, well, I think that your 1st statement is correct (not sure, though). $EXP$ machine can do exponentially many queries to $PSPACE$ machine. So, it allows it to simulate $EXPSPACE$ machine. 2nd argument is true (for deterministic machines).

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Why do you think it's impossible to show that $EXP \subseteq EXP^A$?  The part you wrote about "because" makes no sense to me.  Do you have something backward?  Please proof-read your post carefully.  Also, please ask only one question per post.

Comment: @D.W. If I had someone else to ask I would ask them. You're also supposed to show effort and that you tried something in questions, so how can I phrase this differently? Lastly, these two problems are so similar that they're practically the same question. I edited that part to make it more explicit.

Comment: Your 'proof' for first statement is wrong. I can say that $DTIME(n^c) \subset DTIME(2^{n^c})$. But that doesn't mean that $P$ is not low for $EXP$.

Comment: kuhaku, Take this as a hint to start by trying to elaborate on your reasoning for why it's impossible to show $EXP \subseteq EXP^A$.  See if you can spell out the logical connections more.  Why do those two bullets imply that it's impossible to show $EXP\subseteq EXP^A$?  What's your reasoning?  I gather that you tried one approach to show it and that didn't work -- that doesn't mean it's impossible to show it.  Also, I think you have the statement backwards; do you mean $EXP^A \subseteq EXP$?